# Error when trying to stream file for download using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my code to download at client when user click on a download link

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
                       filename=.pdf");

Response.TransmitFile(FileName);

Response.End();
```

Content Types are of different:
pdf,word,swf,.zip,ppt,xls

But i'm getting the same issue as attached[image].

Comment: You set the `filename` to be `.pdf` - doesn't look like a valid filename to me.

Comment: filename is a default text on the Save Dialog Box so dnt worry abt it..

Comment: Why is the error in a popup? Is there some JavaScript involved?

Comment: not in this page. wy this err is being replicating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use application/octet-stream for all stream type:

```
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition",string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Path.GetFileName(strVirtualFilePath);"));
                HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(_strVirtualFilePath);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the content type at the beginning.

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

Comment: guys, thanks your reply... but i'm getting the same issue at                     Response.End(); ?!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call `Response.Clear()` at the beginning of your code, and set the `ContentType` as suggested by *shrutyzet*.

Comment: thanks your reply... but i'm getting the same issue at Response.End(); ?!

Answer (score 0):

If FileName is a string with an assigned value then remove the line
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=.pdf");
from your code

Comment: thanks your reply... but i'm getting the same issue at Response.End(); ?!